# Accessing lists a referenced element is inside of

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Let's say I got a list of lists, like so:

```
x = [
["spam", "bacon", "eggs", "tomatoes"]
]
```

Then I make a reference to an element inside of the first element (list) in the list.

```
y = x[0][1]  # which should be "bacon"
```

Now I wish to access, having only reference `y` at disposal, other elements that are with `"bacon"`, and maybe even lists next to the list `"bacon"` is part of. Here is more specifically what I would need that for:

```
y = x[0][1]
z = x[0][0]

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, stuff)
        self.stuff = stuff
    def checkstuff()
        # if stuff from different instance of class is member of the same list, things happen

spam = Thing(stuff=y)
bacon = Thing(stuff=z)
```

Comment: `y` is just a string reference. It doesn't know anything about which list(s) it is a member of.

Comment: Yeah @MarkMeyer, I don't expect to be able to do it without some kind of library or creating custom functions, and I don't know how to start approaching that problem.

Comment: You could create a wrapper class for the strings which also holds a reference to the parent list (and index)..

Comment: You can use `.index('bacon')` to find the index, then use that add or subtract from the index

Comment: But this smells like an X-Y problem. What's the real use-case?

Comment: I specified, in the question, a bit more what I would need that for. Does that help @Blorgbeard?

Comment: As mentioned, once you did `y = x[0][1]` it can't "remember" the `[0][1]`. What you could you is simply search for it again `for l in x: if y in l: return l` something like that. Of course that will be problematic if there are repeating values

Comment: You could pass `x, 0, 1` to the class instead of `y`?

Comment: Really, this question is still pretty X-Y. Can you explain why "having only reference y at disposal" is a constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is a bit vague, would add comment normally but rep too low. Here's my guess at what you want...

```
x = [
["spam", "bacon", "eggs", "tomatoes"],
["spam", "bacon", "eggs", "tomatoes"],
["spam", "notthisone", "eggs", "tomatoes"],
["spam", "bacon", "eggs", "tomatoes"],
["spam", "orthisone", "eggs", "tomatoes"]
]

y = x[0][1]
print(y)
indicesContaining = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    for string in x[i]:
        if string == y and i not in indicesContaining:
            indicesContaining.append(i)
print (indicesContaining)
```

This gets you the indices of the outer list in which the element y is contained.
Edit: answer is now outdated, question changed